# How get bitfumes/laravel-multiauth to know my controllers?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using bitfumes/laravel-multiauth Admin, I added my routes to the routes/admin.php but it shows me this error that it can't find my contoller.

> Target class
>   [Bitfumes\Multiauth\Http\Controllers\admin\DashboardController] does
>   not exist.

```
route/admin.php

Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
```

should I move my controllers to path specified in the vendor ? 
Btw, this my first time for using this package, so I don't know how to deal with it.
I followed all the instructions in github.But now I'm trying to modify it in order to make it work for my project.

My controllers only work only if add them to the vendor directroy :

> vendor/bitfumes/laravel-multiauth/src/http/controllers

But this is not practical if I published the project or pushed the project to github that folder will be ignored with the vendor folder.

Comment: please put some code.

Comment: why not create your own multi auth it is simple

Comment: just go to your auth.php file and define new guards and set the model for the guards

Comment: then to authenticate use auth('guard_name')->attempt()

Comment: I did all that and still having the same issue.

Comment: the instructions you gave are for laravel/laravel multiauth ...I have issue with using bitfumes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution for this Problem**

In routes/admin.php

Add path to your controller :\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PlaceController

```
Route::resource('/places','\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PlaceController')->middleware('role:super');
```